# Disable iPhone backup in Catalina

Tags: iphone, macos, backup, macos-catalina, disable

In OSX before Catalina we could use:
defaults write com.apple.iTunes DeviceBackupsDisabled -bool true
to disable iPhone backups 
Does anyone know how to disable in Catalina?

Answer (score 9):

Set the privilege to Read only for the Backup folder (~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup).

Comment: That worked for me. After changing the permissions on the specified Backup folder, I was able to sync my iPhone, my contacts synced, and no backup was created.

Comment: `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` does not exist

Comment: This worked for me. However a couple of months later I forgot I did this and had a hell of a time finding out why backups failed when I did want to back up.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I got a solution for this.

1. update mac OS to 10.15.1
2. Then uncheck above option called 'Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected'

Comment: It will still perform a backup once you manually sync your music library.

Answer (score 2):

1. Connect your device to your Mac.
2. In the Finder on your Mac, select the device (your iPhone) in the Finder sidebar.
3. Select General in the button bar.
4. [ ] `Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected` - **UNCHECK**

   - Automatically sync when this [device] is connected: To automatically sync when you connect your device, select this tickbox.
5. Click `Apply`.

#### In case a case happens:

When clicking on it to uncheck, then nothing happens besides the `Apply` button turning grayed out, rendering it totally useless. When coming back to the devices, it's checked and it syncs.

Solution:

1. Open `Activity Monitor`
2. Find process `AppleMobileBackup` and select it or click on it to be highlighted
3. Go to menu `View`→ `Quit Process` (`Alt/Option` + ` Apple/Command-Cmd` + `Q` → shortcut: ⌥⌘Q )
4. Press `Force Quit`
5. Wait a few seconds and you will be able to press `Apply` button to turn off automatic sync.

Comment: In order to see the process I had to get Update started.  Once AppleMobileBackup popped up, I forced quit, but that just bombed the update process and disconnected the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking doesn't work. every time I reconnect the iPhone it has all the default tick boxes checked - including "Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected" There is no way to prevent Apple from forcing you to sync via finder.